# Optimization of service running with a continuously executing TimerTask

Tags: android, service, timer, timertask

I need a service that should always be running till its stopped explicitly by my activity  and should start again even if it is stopped due to some issue (`START_STICKY` flag). This service should continuously do something (every couple of seconds) using a `TimerTask`. I ended up with the following code.

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // code to execute when the service is first created
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // code to execute when the service is shutting down
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        // code to execute when the service is starting up
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                                   //KEEP RUNNING SOME ERRANDS HERE
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 100L, 1700L);
    }

}
```

Is there anyway that I can optimize this to run continuously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running every second sounds pretty excessive, but is there a reason why you don't use the AlarmManager to trigger an IntentService? Then the system would be responsible for triggering your service reliably. Whether you can achieve reliable 1 second retriggers, I don't know. Seems like a bad idea for the reasons Mark is mentioning in the other answer.

Comment: Ya, I think I miscommunicated :)
All I needed was a service that should run till my Activity tells it to stop it. I needed to monitor something (not every second, but continuously). What's the shortest timespan that the service could be triggered apprx, using IntentService - take a lucky guess?

Comment: 1 second might be ok, not sure. Here's what you need to schedule the intent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) Just schedule a repeating alarm to trigger your service when your activity starts, and cancel it when you are terminated. Make sure to schedule/cancel in onPause/onResume since you're not guaranteed to get onDestroy. Another option here is a bound service, not sure it's worth it though.

Comment: @Matt Hall: I would not use `AlarmManager` for anything this frequent. Ideally, the polling would be configurable and less frequent (e.g., somewhere in the once-a-minute to once-a-day range), in which case `AlarmManager` would be an excellent choice. But the overhead of `AlarmManager` probably swamps whatever gains you might get. It also won't help if the user force-stops the service -- the alarms will be nuked then as well, at least on Android 3.1 and higher.

Comment: AlarmManager's out of the question. It doesn't do things this ferquently. Timer/TimerTask combi's gonna stay. Any better ideas?

Comment: Another option would be an alarm scheduled just to check if your service is still running and restart it if it's not. Then the alarm wouldn't have to run every second, it could run more infrequently. This isn't perfect, but as Mark mentions there's a reason you can't override OS control of service lifecycle.

Comment: @Matt: I like this idea. Will have to test it how it works when Android force closes the app when it's loaded. Thanks :)
Vote up :D